# write multiple results into multiple columns

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset (demand-dataset from a company) in R, which contains 571 different columns with different product-models and their demand over a 48 period. The objective is to forecast the demand for these product-models, which I do with a for-loop. However, when I write the results to my csv file, all the data is placed in one column.

How do I provide a new column for each forecasted product-model. (all forecasts need to be in the same csv-file)

my code:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dataset)) {
  col <- ts(dataset[,i])
  fcast <- forecast(col,h=12)
  write.table(fcast, "results.csv", sep=";", dec=",", append=TRUE, col.names=TRUE) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your fcast objects have all the same length? If yes, you should bind the fcast object to a matrix/data.frame and save it after the loop is finished to the csv-file.

```
fcast <- c() # if size is known you can define the object
for(i in 1:ncol(dataset)) {
  col <- ts(dataset[,i])
  fcast <- cbind(fcast, forecast(col,h=12))
}
names(fcast) <- c(...) # name the columns if needed
write.table(fcast, "results.csv", sep=";", dec=",", append=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: error in names(fcast) <- c(1:ncol(items)) : 
  'names' attribute [215] must be the same length as the vector [9]

Comment: Sorry, fcast is a matrix, so you need  `colnames(fcast)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply this:

```
write.table(sapply(seq_len(ncol(dataset)), function(i) forecast(ts(dataset[,i]),h=12)), "results.csv", sep=";", dec=",", col.names=TRUE)
```